# How to best handle List<Entity>, List<Entity Id>, List<Entity name> efficiently?

Tags: java, collections

I have a java application which uses JPA.

Say I have an entity called `Product` with `name` and `price` attributes (*all* entities have an `id` attribute).

Naturally I can get a `List<Product>` fairly easily (from a query or another entity), but often I want a `List<String>` (list of product names) or `List<Long>` (list of product prices or list of product ids).

A lot of the time it's just as easy to pass the whole `Product` around, but there are two cases where I don't want to do this:

- I'm passing the list to a class which shouldn't have a dependency on the `Product` class.
- It's significantly easier/faster to get a list of ids than full product objects, (but in some cases I already have them).

The naive way to do this would go something like:

```
List<Long> productIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Product product: products) {
  productIds.add(product.getId());
}
```

But I don't like this because it's messy and inefficient. In python I would do something like:

```
[ p.id for p in products ]
```

The "best" I can come up with in Java is:

```
public class ProductIdList extends AbstractList<Long> {
  private List<Product> data;

  public ProductIdList(List<Product> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Long get(int i) {
    return data.get(i).getId();
  }

  public int size() {
    return data.size();
  }

  public Long remove(int i) {
    return data.remove(i).getId();
  }

  /* For better performance */
  public void clear() {
    data.clear();
  }

  /* Other operations unsupported */
}
```

Pros:

- This approach doesn't need to copy the data
- It is a true "view" on the data - changes to the underlying list are reflected.

Cons:

- Seems like a lot of code
- Need a class like this for each *attribute* I want to access like this

So is this a good idea or not? Should I just be creating secondary lists most of the time? Is there a third option I haven't considered?

Comment: Putting a comment not an answer. Just a small tip, you can always fetch the product ids only, not the whole product, (using what I've heard to be called a scalar query). E.g. SELECT prod.id FROM Product prod ...

Comment: Exactly. Perhaps I should have been clearer. Sometimes I can do just that, and there's no problem. Sometimes I already have a List<Product> and don't want to requery.

Comment: You could use one Class that has one method for each attribute.
That would reduce one CONS at least.

Comment: In the latter approach you described, the client could delete the underlying product.  This isn't true of the "naïve" approach.  Which way should it work?

Comment: @Jeremy: Good point. Although the client can only remove the product from the underlying list, not delete it as such. I explicitly implemented remove() and had I not done so, removal would be impossible so the underlying data would be safe. Basically both options are possible. As soon as the list of ids becomes genuinely different, I don't think it's the same problem any more, and a second list is rightfully the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could minimize the size of those per-attribute wrapper classes by having them inherit from an abstract class that has a getAttribute method.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractProductList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
  protected List<Product> data;

  public AbstractProductList(List<Product> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  protected abstract T getAttribute(Product product);

  public T get(int i) {
    return getAttribute(data.get(i));
  }

  public int size() {
    return data.size();
  }

  public T remove(int i) {
    return getAttribute(data.remove(i));
  }

  /* For better performance */
  public void clear() {
    data.clear();
  }

  /* Other operations unsupported */
}

public class ProductIdList extends AbstractProductList<Long> {
  public ProductIdList(List<Product> data) {
    super(data);
  }

  protected Long getAttribute(Product product) {
    return product.getId();
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this. I think the Product class could be made generic too.

Answer (score 3):

Just to throw in another possibility, you could use Apache Commons' Transformer and collect to create a new collection or transform to modify the existing one:

```
  Collection<Long> productIds = CollectionUtils.collect(products, new Transformer() {
      public Long transform(Object o) {
          return ((Product) o).id;
      }
  });
```

Comment: This is probably the most correct way to implement exactly what I want. It's unfortunate that Commons hasn't caught up with generics though, so that and the additional library mean I can't really justify it. Still, +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use one Class that has one method for each attribute. That would reduce one CONS at least.

This is your example tuned with my proposal.

```
public class ProductList {
  private List<Product> data;

  public ProductIdList(List<Product> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Long getId(int i) {
    return data.get(i).getId();
  }

  public List<String> getProductNames(int i) {
    return data.get(i).getProductNames();
  }

  public Product getProduct(int i) {
    return data.get(i);
  }

  public int size() {
    return data.size();
  }

  public Long remove(int i) {
    return data.remove(i).getId();
  }

  /* For better performance */
  public void clear() {
    data.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't implement List, so it can't be used where a List<Long> is expected.